# Android , How to get color of account from Account Manager?

Tags: android, accountmanager

From `AccountManager` I can get the account type and account name,but I am unable to get the account color.How In calendar application we can get code.

Comment: @CommonsWare .In android there are some color set to Corporate or email accounts , how to get them ?

Comment: Finally , I have implemented using CalendarContract. I will write the code shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the code from Calendar app

```
    Uri uri = CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor calendarCursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
int colorColumn = calendarCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Calendars.CALENDAR_COLOR);

      int color = calendarCursor.getInt(colorColumn);
```

The integer returns the color code of Accounts sysnced with Android phone.